# AutomationFactory - Information Needed

Tags: silverlight, com, silverlight-4.0, out-of-browser, comautomationfactory

I am interested in using the AutomationFactory namespace but I cannot find any documentation on what I can use for a sepcific COM. I figure it's because I do not know what terms I should actually be looking up. Does anyone have any resources? In particular I'm looking for information on Excel, Word and Outlook.

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with the MSDN topic here:  [Office Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726434%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

I would then be inclined to create an experimental Windows Console application and reference the relevant office COM libraries.  Write code to manipulate the office COM objects with the benefit of intellisense, get some sembalence of the what the app really needs to do working.

Write a whole bunch of classes and methods which abstract the manipulations you ultimately want to perform in Silverlight from the actual mechanics of office object operations.

The port the code to Silverlight using the `dynamic` type, you lose all the intellisense on the COM objects of office but by this stage you've created a bunch of classes which once ported are what your real Silverlight code will use to do office operations.

Answer (score 1):

AutomationFactory is a class, not a namespace.  It is specific to Silverlight version 4, an execution environment that doesn't support COM Automation by default, only if the app runs out-of-browser as a trusted app.  The MSDN Library article [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.automation.automationfactory%28VS.95%29.aspx), the bottom of the page has a link to a How-To page.

Comment: Thanks Hans - that actually wasn't my quesiton but I found out the answer. I was looking for more information specific to the COM.

Comment: Well, as long as your answer makes sense to you, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The COM information is the same as what you would find in VBA so when I do internet searches i just look for information related to that.